# SQL How to use IF query to create a new column from others

Tags: sql

I have tables where I have a result of 0-1 0 is gone and 1 is. I need to write a query, and I totally don't know how to. If New_Def = 0 a Default = 1 then 'NEW' If New_Def = 1 a Default = 1 then = OLD.

[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: `DO CASE WHEN ...` will do the trick.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `case` :

```
select * , case when New_Def = 0 and Default = 1 then 'NEW' 
                when New_Def = 1 and Default = 1 then 'OLD'
           else 'Unknown'
           end as Newcolumn
from table
```

Comment: Invalid ANSI SQL syntax. A single `*` must not be combined with anything else in the select list. I.e. do `table.*` instead.

Comment: Also, `default` is a reserved word. Delimit as `"Default"`. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words)

Comment: Except from that it works very well!